# Inserir XML em tabela do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xml

tenho um xml com o nome de alguns filmes, quero que quando eu aperte um botão no html os nomes sejam inseridos em uma tabela no banco de dados. Fiz a conexão com o php usando ajax. O problema é que quando eu faço a inserção, o primeiro titulo é pulado e não é inserido.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#bInserir").click(function(){
            fInserir();
        });

        function fInserir()
        {
                $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url: "revisao.php",
                success:function(ret){
                    alert(ret);
                    }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

```
<xml>
    <filme>
        <titulo>
            Assassinato no Expresso Oriente
        </titulo>
        <ano>
            2017
        </ano>
    </filme>
    <filme>
        <titulo>
            A Cabana
        </titulo>
        <ano>
            2016
        </ano>
    </filme>
</xml>
```

---

```
$xml_string = file_get_contents("revisao.xml");
$xml_object = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "estudo");

foreach ($xml_object as $key) {


        mysqli_query($conexao, "INSERT INTO nota (titulo) VALUES ('$key->titulo')");
}

mysqli_close($conexao);
echo json_encode("Sucesso");
```

---

```
create table nota(
idnota int not null auto_increment,
titulo varchar(25) not_null,
primary key(idnota)
);
```

---

Como exemplo, quando esse código que eu coloquei é executado ele está inserindo somente o titulo "A Cabana" na tabela e pulando o primeiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É porque o nome do filme ultrapassa o limite fixado na criação da coluna (25)

```
titulo varchar(25) not_null,
```

"Assassinato no Expresso Oriente" tem mais de 25 caracteres

Comment: Caramba que falta de atenção minha, tenho costume de colocar sempre 25. Muito obrigado!